# How to merge 2 datasets with different lengths?

Tags: sas

I would like to merge 2 datasets with 2 different dimensions.

```
TABLE1: people
gender name
M raa
F chico
M july
F sergio


TABLE2: serial_numbers
gender serial
M 4
F 5
```

I want the result to be

```
result
gender name serial
M raa 4
F chico 5
M july 4
F sergio 5
```

Comment: Have you tried simply merging the dataset?

Comment: This question does not meet the SO guidelines. Please post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

I'm creating here the datasets to illustrate how to merge both datasets:

```
data people;
infile cards;
length gender $1
       name   $10;
input gender name;
cards;
M raa
F chico
M july
F sergio
;
run;


data serial_numbers;
length gender $1
       serial  8;
infile cards;
input gender serial;
cards;
M 4
F 5
;
run;
```

Solution 1: use a proc sql to perform the join.

```
proc sql;
create table result as
select a.gender, a.name, b.serial
from people a LEFT JOIN serial_numbers b
on a.gender=b.gender;
quit;

proc print data=result;
run;
```

Solution 2: use a data step to merge both datasets. This requires the datasets to be sorted:

```
proc sort data=people;
by gender;
run;

proc sort data=serial_numbers;
by gender;
run;

data result;
merge people serial_numbers;
by gender;
run;

proc print data=result;
run;
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)